# App crashes on Database Creation attempt

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I created an sql database using "SQLite Database Browser", dragged and dropped it into my Xcode project, and built the app. It works perfectly well on the Simulator but crashes on the iPhone, with this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
 reason: 'Failed to create writable database file with message 'The operation could‚ 
not be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)'.'
```

Here's my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Creates a writable copy of the bundled default database in the application Documents directory:
    NSLog(@"AppDelegate...Looking for embedded Database file...");
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    // Grab the path to the Documents folder:
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"users.sql"];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Database File Exists in Documents folder!");
        NSLog(@"Its path is: %@", writableDBPath);
        return YES;
    }
    else {
    // But if the writable database does not exist, copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSLog(@"!!NO Database File Exists in Documents folder!");
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"users.sql"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else 
        NSLog(@"WROTE THE DATABASE FILE!!!");
}

return YES;
}
```

Again, this works on the Simulator, but not on the iPhone. (This couldn't possible have anything to do with the file have a ".sql" extension as opposed to a ".sqlite" extension, could it? Cause that's the extensions that "SQLite Database Browser" gives the files it creates...)

Comment: As far as I know,Cocoa error 260 is NSFileReadNoSuchFileError, so it may be because of the extention.

Comment: well, I just changed the file name to end with ".sqlite" - and reimported the file into Xcode, and changed to code to match new filename - its still crashing - same reason. So that's not it....

Comment: try to run the code of the tutorial that you have used on the device and see if that works. If that does, there may be a problem with the db file itself.

Comment: doesn't work. Look, the app runs fine on the Simulator, so why is it not running on the device? Is there anything wrong with my code? I'm assuming you've looked at my code and didn't find any errors in it - is that the case? Also, if there was a problem with the database file itself - how could I find that out? Its opening just fine in the database program, so its not corrupt or anything. Are there some tests I could run on it? Is there ANY other suggestion that comes to mind? What's crazy is that all this was working just fine - till I upgraded to iOS 5.1 - could _that_ be it?

Answer (score 28):

The answer has to do with making sure the "Target Membership" of the sql file is set properly, so that the project "sees" it:

1) click on the sql file in the left-pane of Xcode

2) open/show the File Inspector (right pane)

3) Under "Target Membership", make sure the "check" is "checked"

that's it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This solution resolves my problem i hope it will helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

in my issue:
check this row:

```
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"users.sql"]
```

Check the fileName in your bundle and in code - the error also is cased of different filenames.