# add Separate .sqlite file to ios project

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I have created a myDB.sqlite database from SQLite Manager firefox addon. I want to add this myDB.sqlite file to my project. Then I can write functions to get data from tables.

I tried to add the myDB.sqlite file to project folder & create a filepath like this. But I think this filepath is wrong.

```
-(NSString *) filePath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"document.sqlite"];
    return path;
}
```

Does it correct to add myDB.sqlite file to the project folder? or where should I save this myDB.sqlite file & what is the filepath I should use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add your myDB.sqlite file in your project. by right click your project name=> add files to ""projectName", then add it.

to get your file path you can add this in your appDelegate

```
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {

//Using NSFileManager we can perform many file system operations.
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;

NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

if(!success) {

   NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
   success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

   if (!success)
      NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
}
}

- (NSString *) getDBPath
{   
//Search for standard documents using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
//First Param = Searching the documents directory
//Second Param = Searching the Users directory and not the System
//Expand any tildes and identify home directories.

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
//NSLog(@"dbpath : %@",documentsDir);
return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDB.sqlite"];
}
```

in your did finish with launching method call [self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];

Comment: When I did this myDB.sqlite file saved in simulator folder. But it's an empty file (without my tables)

Comment: reset the simulator and then try and copy sqlite database from simulator.

Comment: Then there is a error "NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to create writable database file with message 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)'.'
"

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378564/app-crashes-on-database-creation-attempt

Comment: Finally got it correct.... Thanks for your help.. sorry I cannot vote up because I have only 14 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have successfully copied sqlite db into project's folder. So you have sqlite Database in your app's bundle now.

So you need to copy database from app's bundle to document directory of device/simulator using following code. Write these in AppDelegate.m

```
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *folderPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    // First, test for existence.
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:folderPath])
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

    NSString *dbPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"document.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if(!success)
    {
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"document.sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
        if (!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"document.sqlite : Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    /** Database copy is not exist **/
    [self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: When I did this document.sqlite file saved in simulator folder. But it's an empty file (without my tables)

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)addSqlFileIfNotExists {

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *writableDBPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"document.sqlite"];

BOOL exits = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
if(exits) return;

NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"document.sqlite"];

BOOL exit = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];

if(!exit) 
  NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);

}
```