# Unable to create folder inside document directory

Tags: ios, nsbundle, nsdocumentdirectory

I developed iPhone app in which i got stuck at one point,

What i want to do is,
I want to copy my Database from `bundle` to `folder inside document directory`

When i try to create folder inside `DocDir` it doesn't getting created and it shows error,

**Failed to create MyDB.sql file with message 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)**

Here is my code snippet,

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"/NewFolder/"];

    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDB.sql"];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if(!success) {

        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyDB" ofType:@"sql"];

        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

        if (!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Where i am doing mistake? please help

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: Did you google that error code yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [add Seperate .sqlite file to ios project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186507/add-seperate-sqlite-file-to-ios-project)

Comment: Yes, but facing same problem even after trying new code which i got from google

Comment: The **error code**. Did you search around what Cocoa error 4 means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to create directory by following code, may you get help..

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/YourFolder"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])//Check
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Will Create folder
```